# Getting "<jemalloc>: Error in VirtualFree():" related error in markLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using `MarkLogic 8`

When I checked `ErrorLog.txt` file I could see the file contains a lot of error text as

```
<jemalloc>: Error in VirtualFree(): Attempt to access invalid address.
```

I searched on google but did not find anything.

Not able to understand the reason behind this error. Please help.

Comment: What patch release of MarkLogic exactly? Did you try upgrading to latest if there is a newer one available?

Comment: I am using 8.6-6.3

Comment: Could you try with 8.0-8.1?

Comment: I got this issue in PROD environment. It's won't be easy to update. It would be great a help if you please explain the reason of this error. I would like to understand the cause of this error and try to fix it.

Comment: A core dump issue, something you rarely see. Please reach out to support, they will want to know about this, and they can guide you how best to proceed..

Answer (score -1):

It seems some issue with the Memory.
Try accessing this [link](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/422/0/jemalloc-memory-allocator)

Probably you will get some hint over the issue.